# Is it possible to disable onBlure event for all elements in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, inspect

with a regular element when I want to inspect it I simply right click on it. but for a drop down item and such things, it is not possible. as soon as I right click on it the parent container closes. so is there any code snippet that prohibits elemnts of the page from firing onBlure when I right click on theme?

Comment: by saying *"dropdown and such things"* do you have any specific element in mind? Please read [ask], then [edit] with a [mre]. Also, `"blur"` is not cancelable.

Comment: In the documentation it says the `blur` event is not cancelable. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event#

Comment: Right click the parent element, Inspect, then traverse the DOM to find whatever element you're trying to target via the DOM inspector.